# Why is Jest updating all snapshots in my project?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs, enzyme

I wrote some tests, which all went nice and green. Then I needed to update my snapshot. Unfortunately, it's after running update snapshots. It seems to have edited all components snapshots. Even for component's I have not changed. When I look at the diff I see this:

```
 exports[`MyComponent should render correctly 1`] = `
 ShallowWrapper {
-  "length": 1,
   Symbol(enzyme.__root__): [Circular],
   Symbol(enzyme.__unrendered__): <FileManagement
     areYouSure="Are you sure?"
@@ -1250,8 +1249,20 @@ ShallowWrapper {
     "adapter": ReactSixteenAdapter {
       "options": Object {
         "enableComponentDidUpdateOnSetState": true,
+        "lifecycles": Object {
+          "componentDidUpdate": Object {
+            "onSetState": true,
+          },
+          "getDerivedStateFromProps": true,
+          "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate": true,
+          "setState": Object {
+            "skipsComponentDidUpdateOnNullish": true,
+          },
+        },
       },
     },
+    "attachTo": undefined,
+    "hydrateIn": undefined,
   },
```

Any help would be great as it's breaking my Jenkins job and I can't seem to fix it. I'm not sure why it adds the keys to the snapshots? Also why does it do it to all of them.

I'm using Node version `10.9` and Jest version `22.4.3`

Comment: I was having this issue when running tests with `yarn` instead of `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

You need enzyme-to-json plugin to make your snapshots easier to read. As for updated snapshots for components you have not changed, somebody else must have changed them, and they did not update snapshots. You need to update your expected snapshots whenever you change the way components render.